# How can I allocate memory for nested zero length array?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, gcc, data-structures

I want to create a struct Ring with nestd zero lenght array:

```
typedef struct Data_Block
{
      size_t Data_Len;
      char Buf[0];
}Block;

typedef struct Block_Ring
{
      int head;
      int tail;
      int full;
      int block_num;
      Block blk[0];
}Ring;
```

How can I correctly allocate memory for a Ring which contains 32 Block, and one Block contains Buf of size 16? Because if I malloc with the right size, the number of Block will become just one.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(Ring) + sizeof(Block) * 32 + 32 * 16);`

Comment: Allocating full block of your structure with variable last element is very risky as pointer arithmetics `ptr++` doesn't work properly anymore.

Comment: Declaring an array in a structure with a zero-length dimension is an extension of GCC and other implementations. As of C 2011, you ought to use the standard method of using an incomplete array type—just omit the length. `char Buf[0];` would be `char Buf[];` instead.

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible, since compiler doesn't know the correct position for the `ring->blk[1]` and elements beyond that. As such it will calculate incorrect structure offset. If you want this to work, `blk` needs to be array of *pointers* to blocks.

Comment: What [user694733](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694733/user694733) writes is mostly right. If you make `Buf` a flexible array member, a good compiler will not allow you to declare `blk` as an array of `Buf`, since their sizes may vary and, even if they do not, are unknown at compile time. Oddly, if you use the `0` extension instead of the standard incomplete array type, clang-902 allows it. But it would necessarily get the array arithmetic wrong. You could use this, though, by calculating the element addresses manually.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I removed the answer because I was not fully clear about _Alignof(Block).

Answer (score 4):

## Fundamental Problem

There is a fundamental problem you must deal with before addressing this task: Constructing an array requires having elements of a fixed and known size.

That is because array element *i* is located by adding *i* times the size of an element to the base address of the array. One can perform that calculation only if the size of an element exists (elements have a fixed size) and you know it (the size is known).

Although you define `Block` to contain a member of zero size (`Buf` is an array with zero elements), you intend to use it as if that member were 16 bytes (an array of 16 `char`). However, there is no way to tell the compiler that the `Block` objects you will allocate and use are actually `Block` objects with 16 extra bytes. You certainly can allocate space for them, and I will show you how, but then how do you intend to use them? If `x` is a `Ring` object, and you write `x.blk[i]`, the compiler will generate code that multiplies `i` by what it thinks the size of a `Block` is, and that will be wrong because the compiler thinks a `Block` has zero bytes for `Buf`, but your `Block` objects are bigger.

## Standard C Versus An Extension

Declaring a structure member as an array with zero elements is an extension (notably available in GCC). The 1999 C standard introduced a similar feature called *flexible array members*. With standard C, a flexible array member is declared with no dimension, rather than a zero dimension.

A flexible array member is an *incomplete type* (C 2018 6.7.2.1 18). In other words, the type is not fully specified. The number of members of the array is unknown, and so the total size of the array is unknown.

Then, in defining `Ring`, we cannot define the `blk` member to be a flexible array member that is an array of `Block`, because standard C requires that the element type of an array be a complete type (C 2018 6.7.6.2 1, “The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type”).

Therefore, this code cannot be made into standard C. This is actually an advantage: The C standard is preventing you from making the fundamental mistake above of creating an array that cannot work because the size of its elements is not known.

Oddly, GCC 8.1 for x86-64 fails to give a diagnostic for this. It should give a diagnostic for the constraint violation. Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2) does issue a diagnostic.

However, we will proceed to consider the code as you have written it, using the language extension.

## How Big Are The Elements?

When a C implementation lays out a structure, it must ensure that each member in the structure is correctly aligned. (What alignments are correct is defined by the implementation, so they vary. However, whatever they are, the compiler must lay out the structure accordingly.) Since structures can be used as elements of an array, the size of the laid-out structure must be such that when one structure follows another in the array, all the members in the following structure are also correctly aligned.

Satisfying this constraint requires that the size of the structure be a multiple of the alignment requirements of all members. For example, if there are members with alignment requirements of 4 bytes and 8 bytes, the size of the structure must be a multiple of 8 bytes, since that is the least common multiple of 4 bytes and 8 bytes. In fact, all alignment requirements are powers of two, so the least common multiple of all the alignment requirements is simply the largest (most restrictive) alignment requirement.

What this means is that, when allocating space for an array of your `Block` objects, you cannot simply use an arbitrary number of bytes for the extra `Buf` elements. You must ensure the total size of each `Block` object is a multiple of the alignment requirement of its members.

C provides a way to know the alignment requirement of the structure. The expression `_Alignof(Block)` is the alignment requirement. So, if you want each `Block` to have `x` elements in `Buf`, the size you need for each `Block` is the size of the base structure (`sizeof(Block)`) plus the size you need for the actual array elements (`x * sizeof(char)`) plus enough padding to round the total up to a multiple of the alignment requirement. You can calculate this with:

```
// Calculate desired space.
size_t S = sizeof(Block) + x * sizeof(char);

// Note the alignment requirement.
static const size_t A = _Alignof(Block);

// Round up to multiple of alignment requirement.
S = (S-1) / A * A + 1;
```

(This is a well-known expression for rounding up to a multiple of `A`. You can tinker with some examples to see why it works.)

Once you have calculated the space needed for one `Block` using the above code (with 16 for `x`), you can allocate space for one Ring with an array of 32 of these `Block` using:

```
Ring *R = malloc(sizeof(Ring) + 32 * S);
```

## Accessing Array Elements

Now that you have the space, how do you access members of `blk`? As discussed above, the compiler does not know how to do this. Unfortunately, C does not provide any assistance. You will have to calculate addresses manually. Since you know the size of each of your `Block` objects, `S`, you can calculate the address of the Block with index `i` with:

```
Block *B = (Block *) ((char *) R->blk + S*i);
```

## Discussion

This is cumbersome and error-prone. The address calculation could be wrapped into a helper function to make it a little better. However, it is generally not a good idea to use complicated code like this. You ought to consider alternative solutions.